# Java - Remotely Connect to a Server using PowerShell and bypass the password prompt

Tags: java, powershell, remote-server

I need help connecting to a remote server using PowerShell in JAVA. I want the connection to be done in the background, without having a prompt for the password and navigate to the desired location on the server (C:\Events\rootdir\), where I will upload a directory from my local machine.

Currently, I am using the following query:

```
 String command = "powershell.exe Invoke-Command -Credential myusername -ComputerName 192.x.x.x -FilePath C:\\Events\\rootdir\\
 Process powerShellProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
 powerShellProcess.getOutputStream().close();
```

However, by doing this I am getting a prompt for the password:

[image]

What do I need to do to include the password call in the command string, so that I connect directly to C:\Events\rootdir\, bypassing this password prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a credential which has your username and password first. This will be a pain by just using `exec`. Use this library: https://github.com/profesorfalken/jPowerShell where you can start a PowerShell session and execute multiple commands.

Or build a `.ps1` and execute that.

To create a credential object:

```
$Username = 'labuser'
$Password = 'labuser'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$pass
```

Then you can use `$Cred` to pass as parameter to the `-Credential` switch.

Comment: Hi Strelok, thanks for your reply. I went ahead with the suggested path. I modified my code to create the .ps1 file suggested with each run (if it doesn't exist) and from there rather than executing Process powerShellProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command), I added this extra line to .ps1 being created: invoke-command -ComputerName "xxx" -ScriptBlock {anything you want to do} -credential $Cred. So that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code:

```
public class PowerShellSession {
    private static String subModule = "PowerShellSession";
    String targetIpAddress;
    String username;
    String password;

    public static Object connectPShellLock = new Object();

    public PowerShellSession() {}


    public void exec(String cmd, String credentials)  { 

        String ex = credentials +" Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {" + cmd + "} -ComputerName " + targetIpAddress +" -Credential $mycred";

        String[] args = new String[] { "powershell", ex};
        try {
            execRemote(args);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        String command = "Exit-PSSession";
        String[] args = new String[] { "powershell", command};
        try {
            execRemote(args);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private String getCredentials(String domain, String userName,
            String password) throws IOException {
        String creds = "$Username = '"+userName+"';$PlainPassword ='" + password
                + "'; $SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $PlainPassword -Force;"
                + "$mycred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username, $SecurePassword;";
        //creds += "$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName " + domain + " -Credential $mycred;";

        String[] args = new String[] { "powershell", creds};
        execRemote(args);
        return creds;
    }

    private void execRemote(String[] arguments) throws IOException {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(arguments);
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process process = builder.start();
        doProcessIO(process);
    }

    // Do the IO for a passed process
    private void doProcessIO(Process p) throws IOException {
        p.getOutputStream().close();
        String line;
        System.out.println("Output:");
        BufferedReader stdout = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                p.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = stdout.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        stdout.close();
        System.out.println("Error:");
        BufferedReader stderr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                p.getErrorStream()));
        while ((line = stderr.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        stderr.close();
        System.out.println("Done");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PropertiesFileReader propReader = new PropertiesFileReader(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/cred.properties");

        String user = propReader.getPropertyData("user");
        String pass = propReader.getPropertyData("pass");
        String ip_add = propReader.getPropertyData("ip");

        PowerShellSession psSession = new PowerShellSession();
        String credentials = psSession.getCredentials(ip_add, user, pass);
        psSession.targetIpAddress = ip_add;//;



        String cmdd = propReader.getPropertyData("command");//"Get-Culture";
        if(!credentials.equals("")) {


            psSession.exec(cmdd, credentials);

            System.out.println("Finished PowerShell remote session.");

        }
        psSession.close();
    }    
}
```